# Cypress - intercept two endpoints in same spec file

Tags: api, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am having trouble intercepting 2 api's in the same spec file. The endpoints are

1. client/users
2. client/users/ipuser

Issue: It captures the users response in ipuser json. Can someone please help on how to use regex in the endpoints.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/client/users/ip_user', { fixture: 'ipuser.json' }).as('ipuser')
cy.intercept('GET', '/client/users', { fixture: 'users.json' }).as(
  'user'
)
cy.wait('@ipuser').then((interception) => {
    interception.response.body.data.attributes.limit = 10000
    interception.response.body.data.attributes.amount = 10000
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(interception.response.body))
    cy.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(interception.response.body))
 )

 cy.intercept('GET', '/client/users/ip_user', {
   fixture: 'ipuser.json',
 }).as('ipuser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use regex match your urls by the ending and will need to escape the slashes.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', /\/client\/users\/ipuser$/, { fixture: 'ipuser.json' }).as('ipuser')
cy.intercept('GET', /\/client\/users$/, { fixture: 'users.json' }).as('user')
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of problems,

- you have two intercepts for `@ipuser`
- if you are dynamically writing `ipuser.json`, you will need to dynamically assign it in the intercept.

Presume it's the `cy.visit('/')` that triggers the requests, this is how it should look

```js
// set up both intercepts at the top of the test
// the more specific URL (/client/users/ip_user) should go last

cy.intercept('GET', '/client/users', {fixture: 'users.json'}).as('user')

cy.intercept('GET', '/client/users/ip_user', req => {
  req.reply({fixture: 'ipuser.json'})                  // responds after the fixture is written
}).as('ipuser')  

// trigger the fetches
cy.visit('/')

// wait on the 1st - presume it creates the fixture for the second
const filename = './cypress/fixtures/ipuser.json'
cy.wait('@user').then((interception) => {
  interception.response.body.data.attributes.limit = 10_000
  interception.response.body.data.attributes.amount = 10_000
  cy.writeFile(filename, interception.response.body)  // JSON.stringify not needed
})

// wait on the 2nd and check it's result
cy.wait('@ipuser')
  .its('response.body')
  .should('have.property', 'data')
  .should('have.property', 'attributes')
  .should('have.property', 'limit', 10_000)
```